SwiftUI GeometryReader reports incorrect size
The width and height reported by geometry is clearly wrong (note that the height is bigger than the width). What am I doing wrong.
GeometryReader { geometry in
    Image(systemName: "photo")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .overlay(
            Text("Width: \(Int(geometry.size.width)), Height: \(Int(geometry.size.height))").foregroundStyle(.white)
        )
}



GeometryReader gives you the size of space available to it.
For example, in MacCatalyst as you shrink or expand the view, the geometry.size
is changed accordingly.

GeometryReader greedily takes up space. So, you’re reading the size of the entire screen (basically). If you want the size of just the image, use something like https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/swiftui-share-layout-information/

Please try
Image(systemName: "photo")
.resizable()
.scaledToFit()
.overlay {
GeometryReader { geometry in
ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
Rectangle()
.stroke(lineWidth: 0.5)
Text("Width: (Int(geometry.size.width)), Height: (Int(geometry.size.height))").foregroundStyle(.white)
}
}
}

Your example code does not produce the screenshot you show. Anyway, the GeometryReader consumes all the space available. When you report its size, it is the size of the frame it occupies, not the size of its contents. To see the size of the image, move the GeometryReader into the overlay over the image, with the Text as its nested content.
